# Dimension three spectral sequences

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, spectral-sequences

If you have two triangulated functors $F,G$, you can [compute](https://mathoverflow.net/a/24151/119012) the cohomology of $FG(-)$ in terms of the cohomology of $G(-)$ and the cohomology of $F(-)$, in terms of a ``Grothendieck spectral sequence''. e.g. if $F,G$ are right derived functors on derived categories. This just comes from the standard spectral sequence on filtered double complexes.

**Question:** Is there anything written about ``$\ge 3$ dimensional'' spectral sequences?

By this I mean something which computes the cohomology of e.g. $FGH(-)$ in terms of cohomologies of the constituent functors, or computes the cohomology of a triple complex with (two?) filtrations.  I'm aware that in principle you could just apply the spectral sequence to $F,G$ then to $FG,H$, but I imagine that it might be cleaner to do it all in one go and it would be nice to have a reference.

Comment: Here's a possibly even more mindblowing concept: what sort of thing is the difference between the spectral sequences gotten from the comparisons in the second compositions in each of $(FG)H$ and $F(GH)$?

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.3187v1.pdf

Comment: @Meow : do you have a reference the for Grothendieck spectral sequence that applies to complexes (and not only objects) of an abelian category ? I am interested.

Comment: @Niels Sadly not, the link (https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24143/composing-left-and-right-derived-functors/24151#24151) I posted only works when the object $X$ is pure.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Is it somehow itself a spectral sequence?

Comment: @meow I don't know!

Comment: @Meow section 2 of this is relevant: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s40062-015-0120-0